# JAVA draw regular polygon

Tags: java, polygon

I am looking for an algorithm to draw regular polygon like triangle, quadrangle, pentagon, hexagon etc.

I guess it`s basically dealing with the fact that all polygon points are located on the line of the circle.

What`s the algorithm to calculate those N points for Polygon object?
After drawing a regular polygon I need to draw another regular polygon based on the first one but rotated by K degrees.

Comment: What is the polygon meant to be drawn to? A java.awt.Image? A JComponent? Make the question more clear please.

Comment: If you are just asking for the algorithm for compute the points, this is very easy to find by searching the web.  You'll even find at least two questions on StackOverflow with accepted answers.  Rotating the polygon and drawing using Java2D are of course additional questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use sin and cos:

```
double theta = 2 * Math.PI / sides;
for (int i = 0; i < sides; ++i) {
    double x = Math.cos(theta * i);
    double y = Math.sin(theta * i);
    // etc...
}
```

To rotate just add a constant offset to the angle, i.e. `theta * i + offset`.

Answer (score 2):

The vertices of an `N`-vertex polygon are located at the angles

```
(2*Math.PI*K)/N
```

where `K` goes from 0 to `N-1`, inclusive. The vertical coordinate can be calculated as a sine of the angle times the radius of the circumcircle; the horizontal coordinate is calculated the same way, except you need to multiply the radius by the cosine of the angle.

In order to turn your polygon by `X` degrees, convert `X` to radians, and add the result to the angle in the formula, like this:

```
(2*Math.PI*K)/N + Xrad
```

Finally, since the origin of the screen is in one of the corners, only a portion of your polygon is going to be visible. To avoid this, add an offset equal to the position of the circumcircle's center to each coordinate that you calculate.

Answer (score 0):

sin, cos, radius, 2*PI / number of sides and a loop